# How do I set every page of a Stimulsoft to show ten rows?

Tags: count, reporting, stimulsoft

How would I set number of records in every page of a Stimulsoft report?

I want every page of report to show 10 rows.

Comment: I've improved the grammar.      It would be useful to know exactly what isn't working now.   Please edit the question to say how many records are currently showing per page.   If you have tried anything that hasn't worked, it would be useful to talk about that too.   A minimal example of a report that demonstrates the problem would also help (put some code into the question).

Answer (score 0):

I've found [the answer](http://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=39881) in the Stimulsoft forum. You can use the DataBand's BeforePrint event to conditionally force a new page by using:

```
if (Line % 10 == 0)
  Engine.NewPage();
```